# XML data to SQL Table

Tags: ssis

At present I have source XML file, from which I am truncating some values using XSLT file. For this I am using “XML task” in control flow. 
Then after getting the resultant file manually I am submitting the resultant XML file to XML source  and then loading the data into an SQL table.

If there a better approach to do the same in one go ?

Novice to SSIS. So if possible could someone give example or link to any example to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSIS Package can contain both control flow as well as one or more data flows. you need to include your both XML Task and Data Flow Task (having XML Source for loading data to sql table). Connect these executable and task in control flow  [using precedence constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx) . This SSIS Package will be automated.

Saving Result from XML Task to file or variable. 
In XML Task Editor,

1. Set SaveOperationResult to True
2. Set OperationResult\DestinationType either to  File Connection or
   Variable
3. Define New Variable or File Connection from Destination property or
   select existing one.

In XML Source Editor, select "XML data from Variable" or  "XML File Connection" and then specify details in the XML location accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure how could I give the result to from XML task to XML source.

Comment: Result from XML task are either to be written to a file or to the Package Variable. Then Refer this file/variable from XML Source.

Comment: see my answer above for the possible steps to achieve this.

Comment: It giving me error while putting the result from XML task to variable

Comment: Error Message is "The value for custom property "XMLDatavariable" on XML source is incorrect". Actually I am not able to select the XML Data variable on XML source. I have mentioned in XML task to output as variable and then giving control to Data Flow task. Then in Data flow task I have placed  a XML source to capture the result from the variable created by XML task. But XML source is not giving the result to select the variable

Comment: set ValidateExternalMetadata = false in the property window by selecting XML Source. hope this helps. if not, watch the variable value in breakpoint mode. for setting Breakpoint, right click on XML task and enable the checkbox on OnProgress Event. Verify the value written to the variable are as expected

Comment: post your xml, xsd and xslt file to help you further. try to File connection approach first to confirm these files are OK. after that you move to variable approach.

Comment: The file connection is working well. This is completed somewhat..but I am trying to not dependend on external file for processing that's why I want to use the variable part. anyway thanks for ur help

Comment: Variable approach should also work if file approach is working, If my post has helped you acheive this, mark this as answer !!